# Angular 6 how to create feature module in library project and not on the applicationproject

Tags: angular6

I am new to Angular 6. I have an application project and a library project. I would like to create a feature module in the LIBRARY project. Can anyone help me how to do this?

From https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules i know how to create a module, which basically creates inside main app\src\ . But i would like to have it in the library project. How to achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
ng generate module customers --routing --project  example-ng6-lib
```

The above command creates module, inside the library project.